# Using UIBezierPath do draw in Rubymotion

Tags: ios, objective-c, rubymotion

I am trying to setup a view allow you to draw a signature. All my selectors and UIGestureRecognizors seem to be working based on what i'm getting in my logs but nothing is showing on my screen after movement. Does anyone see something i'm missing that is not allowing the stroke to show up with my gesture? Any help would be very appreaciated

```
class SignatureController < UIViewController

 def viewDidLoad

  self.title = "Please Sign"
  self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor
  @path = UIBezierPath.bezierPath
  @path.setLineWidth(2.0)

  pan = UIPanGestureRecognizer.alloc.initWithTarget(self, action: 'pan:')
  pan.maximumNumberOfTouches = pan.minimumNumberOfTouches = 1
  self.view.addGestureRecognizer(pan)
  super

 end

 def pan(pan)
  currentPoint = pan.translationInView(self.view)

  case pan.state

  when UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan
    @path.moveToPoint(currentPoint)
  when UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged
    @path.addLineToPoint(currentPoint)
    NSLog("#{currentPoint}")
  else
    p "SwipeGesture unrecognized"
  end

  self.view.setNeedsDisplay
 end

 def drawRect(rect)
  UIColor.blackColor.setStroke
  @path.stroke 
 end

end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue came from using UIViewController vs. UIView. The UIBezierPath only runs under the UIView call. After using this my code worked perfect. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The RubyMotion samples repo on github, has the code to do what you want to do. It uses a custom UIView, called PaintView, which has all of the event listeners and methods for drawing code on touches.

Check it out here:

https://github.com/HipByte/RubyMotionSamples/tree/master/ios/Paint